# update value of a variable outside a class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, scope, pass-by-reference

I have a class derived from a Form, it has textbox for username and password and an OK button. I want it to behave like an InputBox so I can use it like this:

```
Dim Username As String = ""
Dim Password As String = ""
Dim authorization As New Authorization(Username, Password)
authorization.ShowDialog()
    'The user will click OK and I will expect the Username and Password to change based on the user input
MsgBox(Username & " " & Password)
```

The Authorization class:

```
Public Class Authorization
    Dim RefUsername As String
    Dim RefPassword As String

    Public Sub New(ByRef Username As String, ByRef Password As String)
        InitializeComponent()

        RefUsername = Username 'I'm trying to pass reference instead of value
        RefPassword = Password 'I'm trying to pass reference instead of value
    End Sub

    Private Sub OKButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AuthorizeButton.Click
        RefUsername = Username.Text 'I'm trying to change value of variable outside the class
        RefPassword = Password.Text 'I'm trying to change value of variable outside the class
        Me.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

In short, I want to change the value of variables outside the class when the user clicks the OK, how am I going to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add properties to the class to modify it from outside like any other class:

```
Public Class Authorization

    Friend Property RefUsername As String
    Friend Property RefPassword As String

    'this constructor isn't really necessary with this new approach,
    'but I'll leave it as-is.
    Public Sub New(ByRef Username As String, ByRef Password As String)
        InitializeComponent()

        RefUsername = Username ' 
        RefPassword = Password
    End Sub

    Private Sub OKButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                               ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                               Handles AuthorizeButton.Click

        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK

    End Sub
End Class
```

From the outside you then get username and password:

```
Dim Username As String = ""
Dim Password As String = ""

Dim authorization As New Authorization(Username, Password)
'this constructor isn't really necessary with this new approach,
'but I'll leave it as-is.

If authorization.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    MsgBox(authorization.RefUsername & " " & authorization.RefPassword)
End If
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize that ShowDialog returns a DialogResult! :)

Comment: MS likes esoteric documentation :-) Setting the dialog result in the form also closes it for you automatically. You can also set default accept button on the form to have it do it all for you (except checking the result, but you wouldn't need the button event).

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class Authorization
Dim RefUsername As String
Dim RefPassword As String

Public Sub New(ByRef Username As String, ByRef Password As String)
    InitializeComponent()

    RefUsername = Username 'I'm trying to pass reference instead of value
    RefPassword = Password 'I'm trying to pass reference instead of value
End Sub

Private Shared Function PromptUser() As ReturnClass
   Dim currentReturnClass as ReturnClass

   // Dialog Goes Here
   currentReturnClass.UserName = Username.Text
   currentReturnClass.Password = Password.Text
   Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class

private class ReturnClass
   Dim userName as String
   Dim password as String
   Dim userAcceptedDialog as Boolean
   ' Setters and Getters

End Class
```

Your calling code:

```
Dim Username As String = "Default User"
Dim Password As String = "Default Password"
Dim authorization As New Authorization(Username, Password)
Dim myReturnClass as ReturnClass
myReturnClass = authorization.PromptUser()
MsgBox(myReturnClass.Username & " " & myReturnClass.Password)
```